# Correct module interface to use with Raspberry Pi Zero WH

Tags: pi-zero-w

I would like to install a module on my R PI Zero W with soldered head.

The avaliable interface options for the module are

TTL | RS232 | USB | USB Virtual

URL to module: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000989075654.html?spm=2114.12057483.0.0.5ed568basDY1r6

What would be the best interface to choose?

UPDATE:
Full user manual
http://www.yokoscan.com/index.php?m=Download&a=show&id=412&l=en

Comment: Ah, the ad is a bit confusing.  They say you can choose only one of the "colours", which actually mean TTL, RS232, USB, USB Virtual.

Comment: Perhaps you can visit their store for more details: https://fr.aliexpress.com/store/2228138?spm=a2g0o.detail.100005.2.122b42e7GGp6po

Comment: I think, 20% sure - All options are UART serial (1) TTL mean serial 5V logic level (Warning: Rpi is using 3V logic, so needs level shifting), (2) RS232 means +-12V logic level, (3) USB might mean scanner USB port directly (not using USB to serial adapter/cable) connected to Rpi USB port, (4) USB "virtual" might mean scanner uses a USB to serial cable. You might like to ask them for the link to the user manual. ***WARNING***: I am only a friendly hobbyist - no guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up! Good luck and cheers.

Comment: One more warning: The QR/OCR E400 seems to be a "bare machine/module" for professional developers to "embed" into their customer designed case/hand holder etc. They give you the "SDK" for you to develop you own communication interface. In other words, not for ordinary "users". :)

Comment: I'd choose USB.

Comment: How can we know what is best for `your` circumstances?

Comment: @joan me neither ;) i am new to raspberries, never installed a module on it. Just got my first zero and need a barcode scanning functionality for it to process and send codes to my server.

Comment: @tlfong01 just updated with full user manual. Like I said in another comment, it's my first raspberry. What I need is barcode scanning functionality so my zero can process and communicate these scanned codes with my server. Lacking hardware experience here I am not exactly sure how to install this module physically. Dont get me wrong, im enthusiastic to figure out myself, I just dont want to order wrong modules. Thanks!

Comment: As the Pi doesn't support TTL or RS232 that limits your choices. I wouldn't touch it without proper research. But then I wouldn't use a Pi Zero.

Comment: @pibot. I skimmed the user manual and found everything pretty standard. Appendix 5 is about the comm protocol and is also pretty standard. Actually you can start setting up with a WinPC. Of course linux/rpi is also standard to talk to the scanner. You might like to confirm if you really want to start with this OEM version, and not the common consumer/user.  Actually 3V/5V, 9/25 pin connector, default 9600n81 are all very standard thing and any hardware guy. eg lab technician can help you out with any hardware compatibility problems.

Comment: @pibot, and if you indeed wihs to go OEM, I would strongly suggest to start with Rpi4B in R&D prototyping/development stage, and consider RpiCm4 in production. Of course there are too many other things to consider. For example, if project time frame is very long, say 3 years, and the main objective is to learn something, then start with RpiZ/W is OK, or even RpiPico. Have a great project. Last warning: If you have no Arduino, basic hardware C/C++/Python skills, do expect the Rpi learning very steep! Good luck and cheers.